# Django - Save a TextField and FileField of a user together

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm making a basic blog with a title, text and an image field for a post. But I keep on getting the following error when trying to save a TextField and FileField of a model together in one view.

The Error.

```
AttributeError at /new/
'Post' object has no attribute '_committed'
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/new/
Django Version:     1.9.8
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Post' object has no attribute '_committed'
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py in pre_save, line 309
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/appu/Django/Colesk',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/appu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

The class for a Post.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Form for the Post.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title' ,'text','docfile')
```

View for getting the Post

```
def new_post(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit = False)
            post.docfile = Post(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk = post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'core/post_edit.html', {'form' : form})
```

HTML template for the Post.

```
{% extends 'core/main.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h1>New Post</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

I'm trying to save the text and image together so that I can access it for displaying. How can I rectify the error or is there an alternative method for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in this line:

```
post.docfile = Post(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
```

you are associating a `Post` instance itself to the docfile field. The file field should contain an object of type [File](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/file/)

Reference: [Django: Copy FileFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092334/django-copy-filefields)

Comment: Thank you sir, but how do I do it in a way such that the post is saved as one entity? Do I have to write another Model?

Comment: @atsh3 It will be saved as one entity only. Why do you think it will be saved as multiple entities?

Comment: I've tried but I still couldn't make it work, what do I replace that line with?

Comment: @atsh3 Replace that line with `docfile = File(stored_file=original_file.stored_file)
docfile.save()`